# what's this Edittext attribute and how to change it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a phone number editText and I always have this grey label appearing when the phone number editText is on focus. when I remove the inputType  = phone attribute it won't appear anymore, but I just want to design it ( and change the number appear inside) . what's this attribute name and how to change the number inside , or even its color ?
thanks

[image]

the xml:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_code"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneEditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneEditText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.018"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/phoneEditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSendTheCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/sendTheCode"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/phoneEditText" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonChangePhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
        android:text="התחל מהתחלה"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/codeEditText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.202" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLoginExplain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/login_explain"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: That's the system autofill suggesting last typed phone number

Comment: Please share xml code

Comment: hi guys. 
I added the xml now.